# Regex for words in street addresses

Tags: regex, preg-match

I know the dangers of relying on regex for street addresses. However, I must use regex and my addresses are all Australian and come well formatted from one regulated source.

I am successfully using groups to return the street number and street name from the following

```
1 Main Street, Sydney NSW 2000
1A Main Street, Sydney NSW 2000
1/20 Main Street, Sydney NSW 2000
1/20A Main Street, Sydney NSW 2000
U1/20A Main Street, Sydney NSW 2000
```

My (PHP) expression is `~([\w\d\-\/\.\&]*)\s*([\w\d '\-\.\ ()]+)~`

But I am having trouble adapting that to work with:

```
Unit 1/20 Main Street, Sydney NSW 2000
```

My groups give me 'Unit' and '1'

The fiddle is here: https://regex101.com/r/aLRNgp/1

Comment: House number and Street name. I'm using `preg_match` so I populate an array with the regex groups - one for number, one for street.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the regex in question is only intended to match the house number and street name part of your addresses. Your regex looks complicated, however to fix the problem with a prefix Unit use:

```
^((?:Unit )?[\w\-\/\.\&]*)\s*([\w '\-\.\ ()]+)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/KoNCga/1)

Comment: Also, it is not required to escape all these special characters inside of the characters groups. But it does not hurt either.

Comment: Thanks. I've learned a lot from the use of a group in a group :) FYI, I'm now at `~^((?:unit |apartment |apt |townhouse |lot |penthouse |level )?[\w\d\-\/\.\&]*)\s*([\w\d '\-\.\ ()]+)~i`

Comment: You are welcome. Just a tip: To capture everything before the first comma you could use: = `[^,]++(?=,)`